# Exchange pinned array's pointer with an unmanaged memory pointer

Tags: c#, unmanaged-memory

I'm pinning and unpinning with:

```
    GCHandle pinArray(object a)
    {
        return GCHandle.Alloc(a, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    }

    void unpinArray(GCHandle h)
    {
        h.Free(); 
    }
```

before and after an opencl method so array does not move while computing on it. Now I need to exchange backing array pointer with an aligned unmanaged array pointer to have faster read/write operations on it.

But I couldn't find anything like "change value of gchandle backing array pointer" info.

I need something like an "exchange" method:

```
 GCHandle h=pinArray(array);

 // how to?
 IntPtr oldBackingArray=exchange(h,alignedMallocCSpace(10000000,4096));

 // unmanaged operations
 copyValues(h,oldBackingArray);
 compute(array,...); // only passing with "array" for simplicity everywhere
 array[3]=5;
 l=array.toList();
 compute(array,....);
 Console.WriteLine(array[3]);
 copyValues(oldBackingArray,h);


 freeCSpace(exchange(h,oldBackingArray));

 unpinArray(h);
```

does this need reflection to access and change that variable? There are also many C# methods using those arrays inside compute method so will it give more speed even on C# space too? So I'm tring to let C# to use alignedAlloc space for everything using "array" object until I unpin it.

Comment: why do you need to exchange anything? if you have an unmanaged pointer, there's no need for gchandle in the first place; just ... pass around the pointer, either as a `byte*` (or whatever) or an `IntPtr`.

Comment: I'm using array object many times inside compute method. Its very simple inside and I dont want to make it more complex. When I do array[3]=5, it will use unmanaged space from alingnedAlloc

Comment: yeah, but the  moment you've allocated unmanaged memory, **you don't have an array any more**. If you have code that talks in terms of arrays, you simply need to **change that code**; it is now wrong. You need to talk in terms of pointers throughout. Or, hopefully soon, in `Span<T>` (which unifies pointers and arrays, but needs lots of new compiler tricks)

Comment: The good news is that  if  you change `array` from an `int[]` to an `int*`, then `array[3] = 5;` still works identically - except with different bounds checking (memory-violation exceptions etc)

Comment: @MarcGravell but number of arrays passed in as an array objects is unknown. I need nth order unsafe closures for that

Comment: Not true; if you're dealing in terms of unmanaged memory, the number of arrays passed in is known: it is zero. You don't have arrays. But that may be splitting hairs; between arrays and pointers, there isn't much you can do with one that you can't do with the others, but it *will* require different code.

Comment: all of which has nothing whatsoever to do with gchandles; so again: why do you want to "exchange" something in the gchandle?

Comment: When I access array, it will access the memory space I allocated from C space. When I write on allocated space from C++, it will be visible from C#  array.

Comment: No, that simply isn't  a valid thing to do.  When you access an array, you access the data **in that array**. Which is managed memory. If you want to access unmanaged memory, you need to use different code. I am very familiar with this area; what you are trying to do simply isn't valid.

Comment: Since I pinned that array, I can work on it from C++. I just want to alter it so it accesses my C++ array instead of its own pinned C# space.

Comment: Nope, that's not  how it works. Yes, you can pin an array and treat  it as a pointer (that is what `fixed` does, too). But you can't treat a pointer as an array. This shuffle works in one direction only. Your question is a good one, but  the answer is simply: "nope, it doesn't work like that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to. The `GCHandle` relates to managed memory; unmanaged memory does not require any kind of `GCHandle`. Nor is it possible to talk to that memory as though it is a managed array. Instead, you need to accept that the unmanaged data is a pointer and only a pointer. You can abstract over the top of that to hide these details, but it doesn't change the reality. Fortunately, to the casual observer, talking to a `SomeType[]` is very similar to talking to a `SomeType*` - as long as you pass the lengths around yourself.

In the future, the upcoming `Span<T>` does a great job of unifying pointers and arrays, but that is only experimental at the moment.

Comment: Do you mean I should  wait for .Net 10 to have more performance without sacrificing readability? But even if it is managed memory, pinning stops it moving so if I could get internal variable of it, I could change it but how? Maybe I pin gchandle itself and look at its contents as a memory address?

Comment: I declared, pinned and freed an array in an endless loop until its gchandle's addrOfPinnedObject becomes a multiple of 4096 but only with a size of 1000 or similar. Cannot do with larger sizes such as 16M. Also couldn't find to "map" an array to another array's region such that changing first array could be seen from second array.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik arrays never overlap. Pointers can. You seem to be thinking of arrays as containing a length and a pointer, but that isn't the case. In a managed array, the array contents are *directly inside the object itself*; arrays and strings are created with different lengths for this reason. This is why arrays will never overlap: *because they are different objects*. It is also why you can't use a pointer as an array. Performance and coding style are often competing requirements. However, `Span<T>` is available today in the corefxlabs myget feed (but: experimental/early)